# What is problem in this LST code on Landsat 7 data?

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am trying to calculate LST from landsat 7 image using this code. but i cant fix this error. What is the possible solution?

```
// Land Surface Temperature (LST) 

Map.centerObject(geometry,13)
Map.addLayer(geometry)


var cloudMaskL457 = function(image) {
 var qa = image.select('pixel_qa');
 //if the cloud bit (5) is set and the cloud confidence (7) is high
 // or the cloud shadow bit is set (3), then it's a bad pixel
 var cloud = qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 5)
              .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 7))
              .or(qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 3));
              
//Remove edge pixels that dont occur in all bands 
 var mask2 = image.mask().reduce(ee.Reducer.min());
 return image.updateMask(cloud.not()).updateMask(mask2);
};

//filtering satellite imagery
//filtering satellite imagery

//vis params
var vizParams = {
bands: ['B5', 'B6', 'B4'],
min: 0,
max: 4000,
gamma: [1, 0.9, 1.1]
};

var vizParams2 = {
bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2','B6'],
min: 0,
max: 3000,
gamma: 1.4,
};

//load the collection:
 {var col = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LE07/C01/T1_SR")
.map(cloudMaskL457)
.filterDate('2002-03-01','2002-04-30')
.filterBounds(geometry);}
//print(col, 'coleccion');

//image reduction
{
var image = col.median();
print(image, 'image');
//Map.addLayer(image, vizParams2);
}

//median
{var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B4', 
'B3']).rename('NDVI').clip(geometry);
var ndviParams = {min: -1, max: 1, palette: ['red', 'yellow', 'green']};
print(ndvi,'ndvi');
Map.addLayer(ndvi, ndviParams, 'ndvi');}

//select thermal band 10(with brightness tempereature), no calculation 
var thermal= image.select('B6').clip(geometry)
var b6Params = {min: 291.918, max: 302.382, palette: ['blue', 'yellow', 'orange']};
Map.addLayer(thermal, b6Params, 'thermal');

// find the min and max of NDVI
{var min = ee.Number(ndvi.reduceRegion({
reducer: ee.Reducer.min(),
geometry: geometry,
scale: 30,
maxPixels: 1e9
}).values().get(0));
print(min, 'min');
var max = ee.Number(ndvi.reduceRegion({
reducer: ee.Reducer.max(),
geometry: geometry,
scale: 30,
maxPixels: 1e9
}).values().get(0));
print(max, 'max')}



   //Conversion DN to Radiance
 var  radiance = image.expression(
    '(17.040 - 0.0000)/ (255 - 1)* (b6 - 1)  + 0.0000', {  
    'b6': image.select('B6')
    }).rename('Radiance');

//Convert radiance into BT

var bt = image.expression(
  '(1282.71/(Math.log(666.09/L +1)))-273.15', {
  'L' :image.select('radiance')
  }).rename('LST').clip(geometry);
  
  
  

//LST in Celsius Degree bring -273.15
//NB: In Kelvin don't bring -273.15


//min max LST
{
var min = ee.Number(bt.reduceRegion({
reducer: ee.Reducer.min(),
geometry: geometry,
scale: 30,
maxPixels: 1e9
}).values().get(0));
print(min, 'minLST');

var max = ee.Number(bt.reduceRegion({
reducer: ee.Reducer.max(),
geometry: geometry,
scale: 30,
maxPixels: 1e9
}).values().get(0));
print(max, 'maxLST')
}

Map.addLayer(bt, {min:31.412184896766178, max:43.49402720742603, palette: [
'0000FF','green','yellow','orange','red']},'LST');
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is mainly in following function but, your code has a lot of logical errors:

```
var bt = image.expression(
  '(1282.71/(Math.log(666.09/L +1)))-273.15', {
  'L' :image.select('radiance')
  }).rename('LST').clip(geometry);
```

Above function can be fixed as follows:

```
var bt = image.expression(
  '(1282.71/(log(666.09/L +1)))-273.15', {
  'L': radiance.select('radiance')
  }).rename('LST').clip(geometry);
```

and complete code in following [link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/62a01a073c8df51e59257f951052925e) (for an arbitrary geometry in Italy) runs without any problem. However, results have illogical values because your approach is wrong and it must be reviewed.